# Delete object from array in NSTableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nstableview

Quick one. I'm overlooking something...

I have a grouped table view that is built from arrays in an NSDictionary. Each array is a section of the table. When in editing mode and a user clicks "delete" I call

```
- (void)removeObject:(MyClass *)myObject
```

how can i determine which array to send the message [myArray removeObject:myObject]? NSDictionary doesn't have an indexOfObject: method but NSArray does. I suppose I could iterate through each array looking for said object but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the standard UITableView protocols and use this method:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle<br> forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     <br><br>//check the section according to your array, if(indexPath.section ==....
     <br><br>
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
     <br>
    [arrayFoundBefore removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    <br> 
    }
    <br>}
```

I think that's the way to do it, not sure though. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You should know which tableView sent the message (because the method in question is in the delegate for that object) - and therefore you can either create the array in the viewDidLoad method in the tableView delegate, or alternatively figure out which one it is based on the delegate context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with iterating through the arrays. How often to people delete things, and are the dictionaries really big enough to make this a significant overhead?

As a reference point, NSArray's `indexOfObject:` method does nothing fancier than iterate though the array looking for a matching object.